# Using df.column.str.contains and updating a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with two columns.

```
df= pd.DataFrame({"C": ['this is orange','this is apple','this is pear','this is plum','this is orange'], "D": [0,0,0,0,0]})
```

I want to be able to read this C column and return in the D column the name of the fruit. So my thought process was using df.C.str.contains to determine if a certain string appears in each row of C and then D updates accordingly.The elements in C may be really long strings: ex. "This is apple which is red" but I only care if the word apple appears in the cell. I should note that i'm not tied to using str.contains but this seemed the most obvious path to me. Just not sure how I would apply it.

The final dataframe will look like:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({"C": ['this is orange','this is apple','this is pear','this is plum','this is orange'], "D": ['orange','apple','pear','plum','grapefruit']})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this dataframe

```
df= pd.DataFrame({"C": ['this is orange','this is apple which is red','this is pear','this is plum','this is orange'], "D": [0,0,0,0,0]})

    C                           D
0   this is orange              0
1   this is apple which is red  0
2   this is pear                0
3   this is plum                0
4   this is orange              0
```

You can use the following code to extract the fruit name ASSUMING the name of the fruit follows 'this is'

```
df['D'] = df.C.str.extract('this is ([A-Za-z]+)\s?.*?')
```

You get

```
    C                           D
0   this is orange              orange
1   this is apple which is red  apple
2   this is pear                pear
3   this is plum                plum
4   this is orange              orange
```

For the example dataset that you have posted, a simple split on space and extracting the last element works

```
df['D'] = df.C.str.split(' ').str[-1]
```

Comment: If this changes the question completely I understand and will re-ask but what if the fruit was wrapped by parenthesis and no spaces? So instead it could be something like thisis(orange). And I want to return just the word orange.

Comment: You can use df.C.str.extract('this is \(?([A-Za-z]+)\s?.*?') to handle the possibility of parenthesis around a fruit. It works for both the cases

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not specify how the fruit is being extracted, I am assuming that it is always preceded by "this is "; and therefore the following should go a long way:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'C': ['this is orange',
  'this is apple',
  'this is pear',
  'this is plum',
  'this is orange'],
 'D': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}

dff = pd.DataFrame(d)

dff['D'] = dff.C.str.replace(r'(this is) ([A-Za-z]+)','\\2')
# or just
dff.C.str.replace('this is ','')


#                 C       D
# 0  this is orange  orange
# 1   this is apple   apple
# 2    this is pear    pear
# 3    this is plum    plum
# 4  this is orange  orange
```

This uses `.str.replace` to replace "this is " with an empty string.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If the sentences always starts with `this is` and followed by `fruit name` i.e. if third word is always `fruit name` then, you can also use `apply` along with `split()` function such that for each row of dataframe `string` is split and third one of the result is taken to replace value for column `D`:

```
df['D'] = df['C'].apply(lambda val: val.split()[2])
```

Or as stated in other answer simply `split` function,

`df['D'] = df['C'].str.split().str[2]`

Output:

`C           D 
0   this is orange  orange
1   this is apple   apple
2   this is pear    pear
3   this is plum    plum
4   this is orange  orange`